# Does the “Pythagorean Theorem” have a person-neutral alternate title

Tags: math-history

The “Pythagorean Theorem” is a well-known theorem connecting the lengths of the legs of a right triangle to the length of said triangle’s hypotenuse. The title above, which is the name I’ve almost always read, is named after the Greek philosopher Pythagoras. But other people around the world for millennia have also discovered that relation. Is “Pythagorean Theorem” the official name, or is there another official title that doesn’t use the name of any of the discoverers?

Comment: Wikipedia is a good place to start with questions like this. There is also a [History of Science and Mathematics Stackexchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Knowing the relation is not nearly as impressive as PROVING the relation. the Pythagoreans were the first to prove it, that we know of. that is why the theorem bears their name.

Comment: You might be interested in [this blog post](https://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2019/04/17/lets-rename-the-pythagorean-theorem/) by Ben Orlin, which lists many suggestions for renamings (some more serious than others). As far as I know, though, none are standard, and certainly none are as standard as "Pythagorean Theorem" or "Gougu Theorem" (as mentioned in John's answer). The first option is "The Three Squares Theorem", which I quite like.

Comment: IMHO, this kind of issues are not worth the time spent on them. On the contrary, the essential fact is that people agree all over the world on this naming. Why should we torn down this unity ? Of course, you can decide to call whatever you want ; for example you can call it  "Pont aux Anes" ("Donkey's bridge") which was a famous french surname or Gougu theorem or 3 squares theorem, it's your right. Will you be followed ?

Comment: In the [link](https://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2019/04/17/lets-rename-the-pythagorean-theorem/) given by HallaSurvior, one of Ben Orlin's suggestion is to rename it to "Babylonian Theorem" because it was discovered centuries before Pythagoras. This is another nice example of the [Arnold principle](https://mathoverflow.net/q/66075/340165). I agree however with @JeanMarie that it could be hard to convince the rest of the world about renamings.

Answer (score 3):

Certain right triangle lengths (like 3-4-5) were known by the Babylonians and others in ancient times, but the Pythagoreans were the ones to prove it is true for ALL right triangles.  It's also called the Gougu theorem but I'm not aware of a name that doesn't include a person.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhoubi_Suanjing#Contents) and [another page in zh Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/勾股定理#普遍定理的发现), and what I remembered, in a right-angled triangle, 勾/"gou" in Mandarin is one of the short sides and 股/"gu" in Mandarin is the other short side, so gougu theorem doesn't include a person.

Answer (score 0):

"Gougu theorem" is a "person-neutral alternate title", but not sure if it's an internationally "official title".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhoubi_Suanjing#Contents) and [another page in zh Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E5%8B%BE%E8%82%A1%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86#%E6%99%AE%E9%81%8D%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86%E7%9A%84%E5%8F%91%E7%8E%B0), in a right-angled triangle, 勾/"gou" in Mandarin is one of the short sides and 股/"gu" in Mandarin is the other short side, so gougu theorem doesn't include a person.

(Editing an ephemeral and temporary comment into an answer.)